# Python -- switched from Threading to Multiprocessing, now publish/subscribe (Louie) doesn't work

Tags: python, multithreading, publish-subscribe, python-multiprocessing

I switched most of my threading implementations to multiprocessing today and everything went great -- except for louie dispatcher messages.  Granted, that's probably not the latest publish/subscribe module, but I use it because I already have to use it with python-openzwave.  I imagine this has something to do with messages not being able to be sent across processes.  My question is, is there a way to do this with louie?  If not -- is there a publish/subscribe message module that allows it?  Thanks.

EDIT, was asked to post the code:

For example, here is a process that continually runs in the background and performs some computer/network/security checks:

The call to start the check class:

```
_ = utilities.Environment()
```

The environment class (just the init and the main function):

```
class Environment(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(genConfig.LOGGER_NAME)
        self.process = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.run_tests)
        self.process.daemon = True
        self.process.start()

    def run_tests(self):
        self.zwaveReceived = False
        while True:
            self.comp_test()
            self.net_test()
            self.server_test()
            self.audio_test()
            self.security_test()
            self.ups_test()
            self.zwave_test()

            time.sleep(genConfig.SYS_CHECKS_INTERVAL)
```

Within self.comp_test, the publish at the end (I've printed from here and know it is getting here):

```
if compTest > 0:
    wx.CallAfter(dispatcher.send, eventConfig.SYSCHK_LISTENER, orders=eventConfig.EVT_COMP_OFF)
else:
    wx.CallAfter(dispatcher.send, eventConfig.SYSCHK_LISTENER, orders=eventConfig.EVT_COMP_ON)
```

And one of the subscribers:

```
dispatcher.connect(self.flip_sys_btns, eventConfig.SYSCHK_LISTENER)
```

Like I said, I've print-stepped through and I get to where the publish is made, I don't get to the subscriber side.  The code worked well when I was using threads, nothing has changed except I switched to multiprocessing.

Comment: Threads can access the same memory space, but processes cannot, so yes there may be some fundamental differences to how your program behaves now. Can you post code?

Comment: @figs Code posted, thanks for taking a look.

Comment: With multithreading the `run_tests` thread will call `self.comp_test` on the same _instance_ of your class, with multiprocessing it won't be the same _instance_. This answer might make it clearer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29317364/1470749.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test that out tomorrow.